# Count values from divs with the same class

Tags: count

I need help with something.
I have few divs with the same class that have numeric values inside. I need a function that will summarize values from that divs and display the sum in another div.

The example can be found here

http://www.bebke.co.il/%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%91%D7%94-%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%91%D7%91%D7%A7%D7%94-%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%9E%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%92-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%90%D7%99-%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%93/

I need to have sharing icons numbers summarized and the summary displayed in the gray div on the right.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you could do this:

$(document).ready(function (){

```
var summary = 0;
$(".test").each(function(){
   summary += parseInt($(this).text());
});
$(".summary").text("= " + summary);
```

});

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mQS8N/3/)

Should work on your page but instead of .test you should use .ssba_sharecount